# Is an OSI sufficient for a travel doc-related OK TO BOARD message, or should I ask for an SSR CKIN?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, bookings

Just had an airline insert a message in a couple of bookings with them, for check-in staff at the departure airports, that I'm "docs OK" and can be boarded (it's a case not clearly addressed in TIMATIC).

However, these are only [OSIs](https://servicehub.amadeus.com/c/portal/view-solution/891251/en_US/how-to-create-an-osi-element-in-the-pnr), not [SSR](https://servicehub.amadeus.com/view-solution?p_p_id=101&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&_101_struts_action=%2Fasset_publisher%2Fview_content&_101_assetEntryId=968179&_101_type=content&_101_groupId=20195&_101_urlTitle=how-to-add-ssr-elements-to-a-pnr&inheritRedirect=true) CKINs. From what I know, SSRs are more "binding" than OSIs, and other airlines have always inserted SSR CKINs on the very same matter, or both an SSR CKIN and an OSI.

**In actual practice**, is this likely to matter at bag drop (which is where I'll collect the boarding passes)? Will the staff directly see an OSI message on their computers, and will they see it as a clear statement from the airline to the same degree? Really important as the airline has no office in the countries of the departure airports.

Comment: What are OSI and SSR CKIN?

Comment: @phoog SSR=Special Service Request, OSI=Other Service Information. Not very clear in and of itself, but here are links to information about them. OSI https://servicehub.amadeus.com/c/portal/view-solution/891251/en_US/how-to-create-an-osi-element-in-the-pnr SSR https://servicehub.amadeus.com/view-solution?p_p_id=101&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&_101_struts_action=%2Fasset_publisher%2Fview_content&_101_assetEntryId=968179&_101_type=content&_101_groupId=20195&_101_urlTitle=how-to-add-ssr-elements-to-a-pnr&inheritRedirect=true

Comment: Please include those definitions directly in the post.

Comment: @JonathanReez Inserted links